# Passing multiple values from Servlet to JSP but I get only 1 value in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to pass both latitude and longitude values from a Servlet to a JSP but I get only 1 value in the JSP

Servlet page

```
for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
{
    String lat=json.getJSONObject(i).get("lat").toString();
    String lon=json.getJSONObject(i).get("lon").toString();
    lats[i]=lat;
    lons[i]=lon;
    request.setAttribute("lats", lats[i]);
    request.setAttribute("lons", lons[i]);

    System.out.println(lats[i]+","+lons[i]);
}
```

JSP page

```
var len=<%=request.getAttribute("len")%>;
lats[0]=<%=request.getAttribute("lats")%>;
<% String[] lats=(String[]) request.getAttribute("lats");%> 
<% String[] lons=(String[]) request.getAttribute("lons");%>

for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{    
    var locations =[
                       ['<%=request.getAttribute("cid")%>',lats,lon]    
                   ];   
    alert(locations);  
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In the for loop of the servlet page you are setting the value of lats and lons which are the same attribute in each iteration.So in the jsp page you will get only one value which is the value of lats and lons set in the last iteration of for loop

Comment: In the for loop to create two list and return.

Comment: you are trying to set "lats" and "lons" attributes and you are trying to get "len" and "lats" in request object. why is it so? It is obvious that you will not get "len" as you are not setting it in request object..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently written, you overwrite the 2 request attributes (`lats` and `lon`) at each iteration. A request attribute is not a magic container, but the simple object last used in `addAttribute`. So in you JSP, you later only get the value of last `lats` and `lon`.

Assuming `lats` and `lon` and arrays in your code, you should write :

```
for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
{
    String lat=json.getJSONObject(i).get("lat").toString();
    String lon=json.getJSONObject(i).get("lon").toString();
    lats[i]=lat;
    lons[i]=lon;

    System.out.println(lats[i]+","+lons[i]);
}

request.setAttribute("lats", lats);
request.setAttribute("lons", lons);
```

To put the arrays in the request attributes.

Then in the JSP `${lat}` and `${lon}` will refer to the arrays, and you can use `${lat[O]}`, or `${lat[i]}`, provided for last expression that `i` is a scoped variable containing a integer value less than array size.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass Hashtable from servlet to JSP.

**Servlet**

```
HashMap latsMap = new HashMap();
HashMap lonMap = new HashMap();
for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
{
    String lat=json.getJSONObject(i).get("lat").toString();
    String lon=json.getJSONObject(i).get("lon").toString();

    lats[i]=lat;
    lons[i]=lon;

    latsMap.put("lats"+i,lats[i]));
    lonMap.put("lons"+i,lons[i]));

    System.out.println(lats[i]+","+lons[i]);
}

//You can  put these as Session attribute also
request.setAttribute("lats", latsMap);
request.setAttribute("lons", lonMap);
```

**JSP**

```
<% HashMap latsMap==(HashMap)request.getAttribute("lats");
HashMap lonMap=(HashMap)request.getAttribute("lons");
int len = latsMap.size();
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {    
        String lats = latsMap.get("lats"+i);
        String lon= lonMap.get("lons"+i);
        String locations ="[['"+request.getAttribute("cid")+"',"+lats+","+lon+"]]";

         //If request.setAttribute("cid",<SomeValue>); is not present in servlet then
         //remove request.getAttribute("cid") from JSP , Change it to
        //String locations ="[,"+lats+","+lon+"]]";   

        out.println(locations);  
    }
%>
```

Comment: cool i got this working now i am stuck with displaying multiple markers as i am not able to call locations in the for loop in jsp page can u try look into this ..thx :)

Comment: @Nitin yes I will, If you could share your updated code. Have you declared any attribute named `cid` in servlet, if not then remove `request.getAttribute("cid")` part and it should become. `String locations ="["+lats+","+lon+"]"`. I have updated my code with `String lon= lonMap.get("lons"+i);`

Comment: @Nitin I have changed `String lon= latsMap.get("lons"+i);` to `String lon= lonMap.get("lons"+i);` . By mistake I wrote `latsMap` in place of     `lonMap` . May be this could be the reason you were not getting Location .

Comment: i am using <%for(int i=0;i<len;i++) { %> for markers, as i have set attribute for len to json.length and i am calling here,the problem is i am getting only 1 marker the first one, i have assigned 6 coordinates..

Comment: @Nitin you are overriding older value by new ones, you will have to create an array or list of Marker , then on each loop add the marker object to Marker list. After the loop use this list to get all the Objects. Because , in for loop on each iteration marker refers to New Object and at the end old one is lost and you only get vlaues added at the end of For loop.

Comment: @Nitin Update your code with the new one. I need to see what is going on in the code.

Comment: i have updated the code below plz look into it ty :)

Comment: @Nitin <%for(int i=0;i<len;i++) { %> this is just a part. I am not able to see your code.

Comment: Ths is how i am storing the coordinates can u help me with markers..
<% Integer len =(Integer)request.getAttribute("len");     
int ilen =len.intValue();    
String[][] locations =new String[ilen][3];%>

    <% String[] lats=(String[]) request.getAttribute("lats"); 
     String[] lons=(String[]) request.getAttribute("lons");

    for(int i=0;i<ilen;i++)
    {    
    System.out.println("i = "+i+", latlong= "+lats[i]+","+lons[i]);
    locations[i][0] = (String) request.getAttribute("cid");
            locations[i][1] = lats[i];
            locations[i][2] = lons[i];
              }
%>

Comment: @Nitin I don't find anything wrong with your code, it is correct. Just make sure that none of the request attribute are null. Otherwise I do not see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try like follows:

```
    for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++) {
              String lat=json.getJSONObject(i).get("lat").toString();
               String lon=json.getJSONObject(i).get("lon").toString();
               lats[i]=lat;
               lons[i]=lon;   
               System.out.println(lats[i]+","+lons[i]);
          }

        request.setAttribute("lats", lats[i]);
        request.setAttribute("lons", lons[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done to store coordinates..

```
<% Integer len =(Integer)request.getAttribute("len");     
int ilen =len.intValue();    
String[][] locations =new String[ilen][3];%>

    <% String[] lats=(String[]) request.getAttribute("lats"); 
     String[] lons=(String[]) request.getAttribute("lons");

    for(int i=0;i<ilen;i++)
    {    
    System.out.println("i = "+i+", latlong= "+lats[i]+","+lons[i]);
    locations[i][0] = (String) request.getAttribute("cid");
            locations[i][1] = lats[i];
            locations[i][2] = lons[i];
              }
%>
```

with this can u provide me some help with the markers..